# Django Asynchronous Processing

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, cython

I have a bunch of Django requests which executes some mathematical computations ( written in C and executed via a Cython module ) which may take an indeterminate amount ( on the order of 1 second ) of time to execute. Also the requests don't need to access the database and are all independent of each other and Django.

Right now everything is synchronous ( using Gunicorn with `sync` worker types ) but I'd like to make this asynchronous and nonblocking. In short I'd like to do something:

1. Receive the AJAX request
2. Allocate task to an available worker ( without blocking the main Django web application )
3. Worker executes task in some unknown amount of time
4. Django returns the result of the computation (a list of strings) as JSON whenever the task completes

I am very new to asynchronous Django, and so my question is what is the best stack for doing this.

Is this sort of process something a task queue is well suited for? Would anyone recommend Tornado + Celery + RabbitMQ, or perhaps something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you do with the results of the computations?

Comment: Return the result (as JSON) to the user's browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Celery would be perfect for this.

Since what you're doing is relatively simple (read: you don't need complex rules about how tasks should be routed), you could probably get away with using the Redis backend, which means you don't need to setup/configure RabbitMQ (which, in my experience, is more difficult).

I use Redis with the most a dev build of Celery, and here are the relevant bits of my config:

```
# Use redis as a queue
BROKER_BACKEND = "kombu.transport.pyredis.Transport"
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 6379
BROKER_VHOST = "0"

# Store results in redis
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = "0"
```

I'm also using `django-celery`, which makes the integration with Django happy.

Comment if you need any more specific advice.

Comment: Also, I haven't had any problem with using `gevent` + monkey patching with Celery, so if you use the `gevent` gunicorn worker and monkeypatch `celery`, everything should just be magically asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried using `gevent` workers + monkey patching in the past but it slows my application to a crawl. I suspect its due to my blocking connection with MySQL. Would I need to move to a different database?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with `gevent` and other DBs, so I couldn't say. Maybe post another question asking about that?

Comment: The MySQLdb driver is written in C and does not use the python socket module. This means that it cannot be monkey patched and will block the whole gevent loop. https://github.com/mthurlin/gevent-MySQL is an asynchronous version.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Celery and use it quite a bit for longer runnings tasks in which I don't have to wait for the result. For the OP's use case, it seems that waiting for the celery worker to finish the task asynchronously so we can then respond to the AJAX request would still be blocking the Django web app, right?

Comment: Yes, if the call was something like `my_task.apply(…)`, the Django thread would block waiting for the task to complete. This might make sense if, for example, the task is heavily CPU bound… But it doesn't free up the Django thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to make it async (presumably using something like gevent), you could also consider making a threaded/forked backend web service for the computational work.

The async frontend server could handle all the light work, get data from databases that are suitable for async (redis or mysql with a special driver), etc. When a computation has to be done, the frontend server can post all input data to the backend server and retrieve the result when the backend server is done computing it.

Since the frontend server is async, it will not block while waiting for the results. The advantage of this as opposed to using celery, is that you can return the result to the client as soon as it becomes available.

```
client browser <> async frontend server <> backend server for computations
```