# Django asynchronous - on model save function

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I have the following:

```
def save(self):
    for lang in ["es", "ar"]:
        setattr(self, "title_" + lang, translateField(self.title, lang))
    super(Landmarks, self).save()
```

The `translateField` function calls Microsoft translator API, which takes some time to finish executing.

Is it possible to do the same asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is not an asynchronous framework.

You need an asynchronous job/task queue, like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/):

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed
>   message passing.  It is focused on real-time operation, but supports
>   scheduling as well.

[django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) package makes it easier to integrate django and celery.

There is also a [Redis Queue](http://python-rq.org/) project:

> RQ (Redis Queue) is a simple Python library for queueing jobs and
>   processing them in the background with workers. It is backed by Redis
>   and it is designed to have a low barrier to entry. It should be
>   integrated in your web stack easily.

Also see:

- [Django Asynchronous Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535540/django-asynchronous-processing)

Comment: Yes, I know that Django is not an asynchronous framework. I was just wondering of any possible way to do the job. Doesn't it exist of any other way without using a third party module?

Comment: @MohdIsmail ok, nope - you will need a third-party package anyway.

Comment: I'm going to give Redis Queue a test. Thanks.

Comment: @MohdIsmail sure, then take a look at [django_rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) too.

Comment: I'm having a small problem. The input field in django admin are set to `<Job d7474859-3592-4b6c-8e08-ec0ea04b6e6e: realestate.models.translateField(u'Apartment', 'es')>` Any idea?

Comment: Solved it by running a `rqworker` but it runs them a side, it didn't find django model. Any tips?

Comment: @MohdIsmail if you have problems with integrating redis queue, consider creating a new question..thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, you don't need third-party package by any means. This can be done using only django. All it takes is a bit of knowledge about multiprocessing.

Comment: @kroolik; I was thinking about using the built in threading module. I'm not sure about its disadvantages though. @alecxe; I'll try to solve it my own, if I couldn't I'll open another question. Thanks.

Comment: Using multithreading would end up maintaing lots of threads to handle such simple task. You'd be better off with a separate process running endless loop polling the database for new entries every now and then, and then doing asynchronous http requests to the microsoft api (i.e. [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests))

Comment: Aha ok I see. Thanks. Anyway it's fine it worked now with django-rq.

Comment: @alecxe; just when I thought it work, it didn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677971/django-rq-asynchronous-task-after-saving-model I opened a question if you want to check it out.