# Django send multiple responses

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: New to Django,  don't know all the advanced stuff here so maybe quoting my question in a misleading way.

I have set up a Django web server that does some numerical calculation with some network data on the server-side and returns the data to the client. Now, the tasks requested by users have multiple results and they are generated sequentially.

For now, what I'm doing (1) User send a task request from frontend---> (2) calculation is done in the backend sequentially and all the result is generated ---> (3) Django sends all the results in a single response to the frontend to update the result.

Now the 2nd step that is the calculation part takes a lot of time about 1-2 minutes which spoils the user experience on the client side.

As multiple results are generated sequentially, I can show the result one by one to the client as they are generated. But I can't understand how can I send multiple responses against a single client request. I guess this is not possible with HTTP? Can anyone help me how do I tackle this problem? Is it possible to that?

Comment: Two possible ways, 1. polling, 2. using web sockets (django channels)

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't.

If the response is made of 2 parts, where one is easy to get and the other one takes a long time I would suggest you split this into 2 different calls in the FE.

Another possible option is to assign an ID to the calculation and return an immediate response with a link to where the FE can pick up the result. The FE would then need to call that pick-up link in a loop until the calculation finishes. You would in this case need to store (at least temporarily) the request ids and the calculation results.

The second option seems to me like a lot of hassle. The concept of worker queues is what's usually used when you need to run background tasks, but that might be an overkill for 1-2 second jobs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535540/django-asynchronous-processing#4536676)) and the FE would still need to pick up the result with another call.

**EDIT:** For completeness - there are asynchronous bi-directional ways to communicate nowadays. For example GraphQL has something called subscriptions ([docs here](https://graphql.org/blog/subscriptions-in-graphql-and-relay/)). These are however by no means out of the box Django tools and will probably require a lot of overhead.